# Getting old value of field before detecting a set with aspectj

Tags: java, aspectj

When using aspectj I have following pointcut:

```
pointcut contentFieldSetter(DataModelEntity dme, Object newValue) : set(!static !final * DataModelEntity+.*)
            && target(dme) 
            && args(newValue)
            && !@annotation(ChildField);


    before(DataModelEntity dme, Object newValue) : contentFieldSetter(dme, newValue) {
         System.out.println(dme.getClass().getSimpleName()+ "." + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName()+ ": change detected");
    }
```

This pointcut also gets called if the same value already present in a field is assigned. Is there an effective way to get the value before set and compare them, so that my print only gets called if there is a "true" change?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do that, e.g. by binding the old value to an advice parameter. If you know which field to access, you can simply access the current value `dme.myField` from a privileged aspect, because you bound `target(dme)` already. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66648599/1082681).

In order to implement it in a more generic way, you have to determine the `Field` instance in the advice and read its value via reflection:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.SoftException;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.FieldSignature;

public privileged aspect MyAspect {
  void around(Object instance, Object newValue) :
    set(* *) && target(instance) && args(newValue)
  {
    Object oldValue;
    try {
      oldValue = ((FieldSignature) thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature()).getField().get(instance);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new SoftException(e);
    }
    if (oldValue == null && newValue != null || oldValue != null && !oldValue.equals(newValue))
      System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + ": " + oldValue + " -> " + newValue);
    proceed(instance, newValue);
  }
}
```

Of course, your variant of using a `before()` advice is simpler than my `around()` variant. If you only want to log something and do not wish to modify the value before proceeding, a before-advice would be better. But when trying this, I got an `IllegalAccessException` when trying to access the field, despite `privileged aspect`. In the around-advice, it simply works. The reason is that using manual reflection in an advice is of course not covered by `privileged`. The difference between the two advice types is that the code in the around-advice accessing the field is generated inside the target class, while the after-advice code lives in the aspect. Therefore, reflective access to private, protected and package-scoped members has to obey the usual reflection rules and needs explicit access permission.

Anyway, here is a workaround for the before-advice:

```java
  before(Object instance, Object newValue) :
    set(* *) && target(instance) && args(newValue)
  {
    Object oldValue;
    try {
      Field field = ((FieldSignature) thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature()).getField();
      field.setAccessible(true);
      oldValue = field.get(instance);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new SoftException(e);
    }
    if (oldValue == null && newValue != null || oldValue != null && !oldValue.equals(newValue))
      System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + ": " + oldValue + " -> " + newValue);
  }
```

Comment: FYI, I created AspectJ issue [#154, Access to original field value for `set()`](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/issues/154).